# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint even if instance is provided to ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model as follows:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    '''Basic Info'''
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='name',
        null=True)
    alias_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='alias name',
        blank=True,
        null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='last name',
        null=True)
```

And a simple view to create or update this basic info as follows:

```
class PersonalInfoCreateUpdateView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("posting a request.")
        instance, created = self.child_model.objects.get_or_create(
             user=self.request.user)
        form = PersonalInfoForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance) # I am instantiating the form with a previous record
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() # Given that I have passed the instance to form,
                        # I expect this to work but it does not.
            return redirect(reverse(self.post_redirect_url))
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)

    def get(self, request):
        instance, created = self.child_model.objects.get_or_create(
             user=self.request.user)
        form = PersonalInfoForm(instance=instance)
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)
```

And my form is:

```
class PersonalInfoForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['name', 'alias_name', 'last_name']
```

and here's the error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/basic-info

Django Version: 2.2.1
Python Version: 3.6.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_jalali',
 'core',
 'django_extensions']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (duplicate key value violates unique constraint "core_person_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/amir/projects/jazb/core/views.py" in post
  57.             form.save()

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  458.             self.instance.save()

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  779.                 force_update, using, update_fields,

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  870.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  908.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1186.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1335.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  99.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  67.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  76.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/owj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /basic-info
Exception Value: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "core_person_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.
```

I know the duplicate error is fairly common. I also know that the way to resolve it is to pass an instance of the record to be updated to the form. But it's not working in my case. 
What am I missing?

Comment: your code is fine to get user and update user,it should not get any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. There seems to be a weird incompatibility between `get_or_create` method and `postgres`. I handled things manually and the error went away:

```
def get(self, request):
    # instance, created = self.child_model.objects.get_or_create(
    #     user=self.get_object())
    try:
        instance = Person.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        form = PersonalInfoForm(instance=instance)
        context = self.get_context_data()
        context[self.context_object_name] = form
    except Person.DoesNotExist:
        instance = Person.objects.create(user=self.request.user)
        form = PersonalInfoForm(instance=instance)
        context = self.get_context_data()
    return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)
```